# How can I write a rule in gitignore to ignore all files except directories in some directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

So lets say I have a directory structure like so

```
uploads/
--dir1/
----one.txt
----two.txt
----dir2/
------one.txt
------two.txt
```

I would like any directory and sub directories of uploads to be tracked but not any files in it with the exception of a dummy file because git doesn't track directories.

I would think something like this would work but it doesn't.

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you tell it to ignore `*`, Git will not recurse into any subdirectories (even though you have a “unignore” pattern that might match something *inside* one of the directories).

There is a bit of the [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) pattern language that might help though. A trailing slash forces the pattern to only apply to directories. So, you should be able to use this:

```
# .gitignore
*
!.keep
!*/
```

In the demonstration below I use the above `.gitignore` and have an additional file (named `do-not-keep`) alongside each `.keep` file. You can see that it works for multiple levels of subdirectories and does not show the other files. You will have to arrange for each directory to have its own `.keep` (or whatever) via some independent method.

```
% git status --short -uall
?? a/.keep
?? a/b/.keep
?? a/b/c/.keep
?? a/b/c/d/.keep
?? e/.keep
?? e/f/.keep
?? e/f/g/.keep
?? h/.keep
?? h/i/.keep
?? j/.keep
```

This was done with Git 1.7.3.1, but I expect that it will work for other versions as well.

The demonstration setup:

```
% git init
% mkdir -p a/b/c/d e/f/g h/i j
% zargs -i.. -- **/*(/) -- touch ../.keep ../do-not-keep
% tree -aI .git .                                       
.
|-- .gitignore
|-- a
|   |-- .keep
|   |-- b
|   |   |-- .keep
|   |   |-- c
|   |   |   |-- .keep
|   |   |   |-- d
|   |   |   |   |-- .keep
|   |   |   |   `-- do-not-keep
|   |   |   `-- do-not-keep
|   |   `-- do-not-keep
|   `-- do-not-keep
|-- e
|   |-- .keep
|   |-- do-not-keep
|   `-- f
|       |-- .keep
|       |-- do-not-keep
|       `-- g
|           |-- .keep
|           `-- do-not-keep
|-- h
|   |-- .keep
|   |-- do-not-keep
|   `-- i
|       |-- .keep
|       `-- do-not-keep
`-- j
    |-- .keep
    `-- do-not-keep

10 directories, 21 files
```

Comment: Don't you also need to have `!.gitignore` listed in the sub-dir's own `.gitignore` file in order for the ignore file itself to be tracked by git?

Comment: @beporter: I would usually just manually track it with `git add -f .gitignore` (when it is tracked, it does not matter whether it would have been ignored or not). But, if you did not want to take that one-time “force” step, then you could add that extra entry (or, maybe better, `!/.gitignore` to only unignore the first-level `.gitignore`).