# How can I get the equivalent of .hgignore's regular expressions ^var/(?!\log|.dummy) and ^var/log/(?!\.dummy) in .gitignore?

Tags: git, mercurial, gitignore, hgignore

I am converting my Mercurial repository to Git. Part of the file system looks like this:

```
|-- .gitignore
|-- .hgignore
`-- var
    |-- .dummy
    |-- asdf
    `-- log
        |-- .dummy
        `-- asdf
```

My .hgignore file uses regular expressions. Part of my .hgignore file is as follows:

```
^var/(?!\log|.dummy)
^var/log/(?!\.dummy)
```

I want to track the `.dummy` files but not the `asdf` files. `hg status` returns:

```
? var/.dummy
? var/log/.dummy
```

How can I get the same effect in .gitignore? I have tried the following:

```
/var/**/*
!/var/.dummy
!/var/log/.dummy
```

But this will not ignore `var/asdf` as desired. How can I track `var/.dummy` and `var/log/.dummy` and ignore `var/asdf` and `var/log/asdf`?

Comment: `**` does not have a special meaning in Git exclude patterns. It ends up meaning the same as `*` (it does not mean “match the following at any depth”).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are only using the `.dummy` files as placeholders to make sure that you always get those particular (nearly empty) directories when you make a clean checkout, then you should probably just exclude `/var` and use `git add -f var/.dummy var/log/.dummy` to start explicitly tracking the placeholder files. The effective result is that you will ignore everything except the `.dummy` files that you explicitly tracked.

On the other hand, if you plan on expanding the hierarchy of nearly empty directories beyond just `var/log`, then you might be able to make use of a bit of explanation.

The rules are described in [*gitignore(5)*](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), but sometimes it is difficult to make sense of all the rules and how they interact. The important part is that the last rule wins, and that later rules can only be effective if the directories they act on are not already wholly ignored. This means that you if you have ignored directories, you have to unignore them before you can unignore a bit of their contents (while re-ignoring the rest of their contents).

---

If you want to automatically ignore everything except `.dummy` files under `var`, then the simplest way of doing this involves putting a `.gitignore` file in your `var` directory instead of doing it at the top level. I described this solution in another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876168/how-can-i-write-a-rule-in-gitignore-to-ignore-all-files-except-directories-in-som/3877584#3877584).

```
# var/.gitignore
*
!/.gitignore
!.dummy
!*/
```

1. Ignore everything in this directory (`var`).
2. But, do not ignore this one .gitignore file (you can leave this out if you are willing to do `git add -f` to start tracking this `.gitignore` file).
3. Also, do not ignore `.dummy` files at any depth in the hierarchy rooted at this directory (`var`).
4. Also, do not ignore any directories at any depth under this directory (`var`).
   Without this rule, the first rule will ignore the subdirectories and Git would never even open them to look for `.dummy` files.

The last two patterns are “recursive” because they do not have a non-trailing slash (meaning that `*` will match slashes in addition to other characters). A trailing slash makes the pattern match only directories. Leading and embedded slashes effectively anchor the pattern to the location of the `.gitignore` file (or the root of the repository for patterns from other exclude files).  The idea is that a plain `*.o` should match anywhere, but `dir/*.o` should only match items directly under `dir` (and we can use `/*.o` for this latter effect in `dir/.gitignore`).

---

If you can not tolerate a `var/.gitinore` file, then you can still do what you asked, but you can not automatically “unignore” new `.dummy` files anywhere under `var` without editing the exclude patterns.

```
# .gitignore at root of repository
/var/*
!/var/.dummy

!/var/log/
/var/log/*
!/var/log/.dummy
```

1. Ignore everything under the `var` directory that is a sibling of this `.gitignore` file.
2. But, do not ignore the `var/.dummy`.
3. Also, do not ignore the directory `var/log`.
4. But, ignore everything directly in `var/log`.
5. But, do not ignore `var/log/.dummy`.

The pattern is: unignore an interesting directory (skip this the first time, since everything is “unignored” by default), ignore what is in the directory, unignore the `.dummy` file in it. Repeat the pattern for each deeper part of the hierarchy.

You can replace `log` with `*` to make it work for any directory directly under `var`, but it will not automatically work for directories that are deeper (e.g. it would work for `var/cache/.dummy`, but not for `var/log/ssh/.dummy`). This is because we are using non-trailing slashes and anchor the patterns. To manually make it work, you have to repeat the pattern to generate more exclusion rules for the deeper parts (unignore interesting dir, ignore contents of dir, unignore file).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to exclude `.dummy` with regex. Just ignore everything and manually add then all your `.dummy`.

Ignore affects only on the status command result.

Comment: I like the main idea of “just ignore everything and `git add -f` your placeholders”, but the exclude patterns does affect more than just the status command (e.g. `git add --all`).